# Using siunitx, how to simultaneously align values by decimal points and in the center in all columns of table

Tags: tables

I have a table with five columns, containing decimal numbers and powers of 10 and I am trying to use the siunitx package for the formatting. What I would like to have in the end are

1. centered values
2. values aligned by the second decimal point
3. the above two for all five columns.

Here is the code for a simplified version of the table, to allow for easier reading:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Sample Table with Decimal Alignment}
\label{table:decimal-alignment}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l|S}
Item & {Value} \\ \hline
A    & 123.45  \\
B    & 67.890  \\
C    & 0.12    \\
D    & 9876.5  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

[image: Screenshot of resulting table]

Comment: Tell `S` what data to make room for `S[table-format=4.3]`, I don't think it can be don't automatically as the S function does not know what data comes in the column

Comment: BTW: don't use the `center` env to center inside a float. The float (here `table`) and `center` both adds vertical space above and below. Replace `\begin{center}` by `\centering` and remove `\end{center}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1):

If you specify the column type as `S`, without an optional argument, the decimal marker will be placed in the center. The resulting symmetric layout (as far as the decimal marker is concerned) is rarely optimal, especially as it tends to be wasteful in terms of horizontal space taken up by the column.

To get an asymmetric layout, you need to provide a suitable value for the `table-format` option of the `S` column type. For the table at hand, this should be `table-format=4.3`, as the one of the number has 4 digits to the left of its decimal marker while another number has 3 digits ot the right of its decimal marker.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Sample Table}
\label{table:decimal-alignment}
\centering
\smallskip
\begin{tabular}{|l|S|S[table-format=4.3]|}
\hline
Item & {Value} & {Value} \\ \hline
A    & 123.45  & 123.45  \\
B    & 67.890  & 67.890  \\
C    & 0.12    & 0.12    \\
D    & 9876.5  & 9876.5  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```